TypeORM Module Crashes on Startup in Kubernetes
We are trying to build some REST APIs with a HANA database as backend. The APis are written in NestJS + TypeORM, and being executed in Kubernetes.
We are declaring the TypeOrm module as follows:
@Module({
  imports: [
    HttpModule,
    TypeOrmModule.forRootAsync({
      useFactory: () => ({
        type: 'sap',
        host: process.env.HANA_DB_HOST,
        port: parseInt(process.env.HANA_DB_PORT),
        schema: process.env.HANA_DB_SCHEMA,
        username: process.env.HANA_DB_USERNAME,
        password: process.env.HANA_DB_PASSWORD,
        encrypt: true,
        sslValidateCertificate: false,
        entities: [EntitySetup, EntitySchema],
        logging: 'all',
        logging: true,
        pool: {
          requestTimeout: 80000,
        },
        //synchronize: true,
        migrationsTableName: 'cdf_databricks_dervice_migrations',
      }),
    }),
    TypeOrmModule.forFeature([EntitySetup, EntitySchema]),
  ],

})
export class AppModule {}

When we run our APIs on a local environment, we are able to sucessfully execute them. But when we deploy the code to Kubernetes, our pod goes into a CrashLoopBackoff state with an exit code of 139, which indiates a system interrupt. Unfortunately the pod does not log any information that can help us troubleshoot this.
We tried a process of elimination an the moment we remove the TypeOrmModule.... section from the modules file, the process starts up fine. What we have investigated do far:

The environment variables for the database look OK at the pod level
Running this directly from docker on our local system works fine as well.
Tried the TypeOrmModule.forRoot instead of forRootAsync

However we are not able to see any logs in the Kubernetes pod, as the pod crashes at the very beginning.
So I had some questions like:

Can the logging in TypeORM enhanced to find what is happening when the module is being booted up?
Is there any other way we can load this module, without bootstrapping at the start?
Any other suggestions for troubleshooting


No one can give you a definitive answer without logs. This sounds most like a connectivity failure at the network layer. See if you can can spin up a pod which has a db client, and have the client connect to your DB. That will rule out connectivity and credentials. At which point you can look at a query log on the DB side (set that up), and see what the client is doing before crashing. That will give you some clues.
